# getting knockout js error magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, totals

I added a custom row for fee on cart totals,

My code for knockout js binding is

```
<!-- ko if: !getValue().0 --> <tr class="totals hfee excl">
    <th class="mark" colspan="1" scope="row" data-bind="text: title"></th>
    <td class="amount">
        <span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue()"></span>
    </td> </tr> <!-- /ko -->
```

and error coming

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unable to parse bindings. Bindings value: if:
>   !getValue().0  Message: Unexpected number
>       at new Function ()
>       at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:2624)

anyone have any suggestions then please share.

Comment: replace to !getValue()[0]

Comment: try <!-- ko ifnot: getValue()[0] -->

Answer (score 1):

try

`<!-- ko ifnot: getValue()[0] -->`

instead of

```
<!-- ko if: !getValue().0 -->
```